# how to get table content with python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the content of table in this site: https://dapo.kemdikbud.go.id/sp/3/100203
using BeautifulSoup. here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://dapo.kemdikbud.go.id/sp/3/100203"

html = requests.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.content,'html.parser')
table = bs.find('table')

print(table)
```

The code above return None although I can clearly see the table tag using inspect element. Is there anything special about the table on that site so I can't get that table?. Is there anyone here who can teach me someway to get that table?

Thanks for advice

Comment: Are you aware that most sites use JavaScript? Turn it off and you will *clearly* see there's no table in the HTML source.

Comment: @baduker sorry I'm not aware of that. can you tell me how to get that table? or there is any source for me to learn that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page uses JavaScript to load the data. You can use next example how to simulate the Ajax request:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

api_url = "https://dapo.kemdikbud.go.id/rekap/progresSP"

params = {
    "id_level_wilayah": "3",
    "kode_wilayah": "100203",
    "semester_id": "20211",
    "bentuk_pendidikan_id": "sd",
}

data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                   nama                            sekolah_id      npsn  jumlah_kirim  ptk  pegawai   pd  rombel  jml_rk  jml_lab  jml_perpus induk_kecamatan kode_wilayah_induk_kecamatan induk_kabupaten kode_wilayah_induk_kabupaten induk_provinsi kode_wilayah_induk_provinsi bentuk_pendidikan status_sekolah      sinkron_terakhir                                                                                     sekolah_id_enkrip
0           SD NEGERI 021II RANTAU IKIL  204F8A5C-0C26-E111-A3F1-2B17E5354A2F  10500987             2    8        2  113       6       6        0           1    Kec. Jujuhan                     100203        Kab. Bungo                     100200      Prov. Jambi                    100000                  SD         Negeri  30 Aug 2021 23:30:36  73AACC97A35BDBA1F3C1                                                                                
1                SD NEGERI 035II JUMBAK  007B8E5D-0C26-E111-9822-37F4923520DC  10500968            14    8        3  129       6       6        0           1    Kec. Jujuhan                     100203        Kab. Bungo                     100200      Prov. Jambi                    100000                  SD         Negeri  01 Sep 2021 21:06:41  F13FE7A8DB315250DA86                                                                                
2         SD NEGERI 043II TANJUNG BELIT  50788D5C-0C26-E111-ABC2-51635D231DDF  10500628             3   12        1  184       7       9        0           1    Kec. Jujuhan                     100203        Kab. Bungo                     100200      Prov. Jambi                    100000                  SD         Negeri  19 Aug 2021 21:27:51  170640D252D05645191D                                                                                
3         SD NEGERI 046II SIRIH SEKAPUR  40B88D5C-0C26-E111-9EB2-F136D2B7FCDE  10500631            16    7        2  130       6       6        1           1    Kec. Jujuhan                     100203        Kab. Bungo                     100200      Prov. Jambi                    100000                  SD         Negeri  18 Aug 2021 06:52:17  5C8B919D286AD009C0B3                                                                                
4                SD NEGERI 053II PENUAL  C0A5A75D-0C26-E111-A9ED-91076000BDB4  10500638            12    5        3   76       6       6        0           1    Kec. Jujuhan                     100203        Kab. Bungo                     100200      Prov. Jambi                    100000                  SD         Negeri  30 Aug 2021 22:33:16  EDB4FEEF80886D32A0E2                                                                                
5   SD NEGERI 066II SIMPANG RANTAU IKIL  F0652960-0C26-E111-87C3-8B0DA08DE057  10500619            28    9        3  212       8       7        0           1    Kec. Jujuhan                     100203        Kab. Bungo                     100200      Prov. Jambi                    100000                  SD         Negeri  01 Sep 2021 06:24:01  D8523D5B2229842B9D2B                                                                                
6        SD NEGERI 083II RANTAU PANJANG  50C9BF5C-0C26-E111-AD10-798372F8DBFC  10500667            24    7        2  154       6       6        0           1    Kec. Jujuhan                     100203        Kab. Bungo                     100200      Prov. Jambi                    100000                  SD         Negeri  28 Aug 2021 08:50:08  F18C037BC061706D1F6E                                                                                
7         SD NEGERI 096II UJUNG TANJUNG  F0DF8B5C-0C26-E111-863B-67FE97243CBD  10500646            11    8        1   95       6       6        0           1    Kec. Jujuhan                     100203        Kab. Bungo                     100200      Prov. Jambi                    100000                  SD         Negeri  07 Aug 2021 09:11:51  F2D3AE51BF4E519B0FE4                                                                                
8           SD NEGERI 120II PULAU JELMU  40905C5C-0C26-E111-868A-891E4E7C16D0  10500578             8   10        2  162       6       6        0           1    Kec. Jujuhan                     100203        Kab. Bungo                     100200      Prov. Jambi                    100000                  SD         Negeri  23 Aug 2021 11:03:10  C4FB189ABDEF4B81D8F0                                                                                
9            SD NEGERI 160II DUSUN BARU  20FD2660-0C26-E111-B681-8B5A1DC847DD  10500586             5    7        2   78       6       6        0           1    Kec. Jujuhan                     100203        Kab. Bungo                     100200      Prov. Jambi                    100000                  SD         Negeri  20 Aug 2021 09:28:49  8F88CFAFF78DC2C54903                                                                                
10   SD NEGERI 163II DUSUN BARU PETENUN  E0128C5C-0C26-E111-84CC-EF95E3EBE2F9  10500589            25    9        3  209       7       7        0           1    Kec. Jujuhan                     100203        Kab. Bungo                     100200      Prov. Jambi                    100000                  SD         Negeri  31 Aug 2021 14:59:37  A9A78F5AE28F5D22B360                                                                                
11                SD NEGERI 212II TUKUM  40A28C5C-0C26-E111-A802-97C5FFEE2AA8  10500797            24    9        2  174       7       7        0           0    Kec. Jujuhan                     100203        Kab. Bungo                     100200      Prov. Jambi                    100000                  SD         Negeri  02 Sep 2021 10:15:51  4CD97FE4665C4AED0634                                                                                
12       SD NEGERI 221II TALANG PAMESUN  1094035C-0C26-E111-A4B7-17EB296E8ECD  10500772            12   11        1  144       7       7        1           1    Kec. Jujuhan                     100203        Kab. Bungo                     100200      Prov. Jambi                    100000                  SD         Negeri  31 Aug 2021 23:55:39  3ECD57BD781462C51CDA                                                                                
13             SD NEGERI 227/II TUKUM I  AC289C18-1B0F-4609-8903-2C4E2DF78EDF  70000176            21    4        1   61       3       3        0           1    Kec. Jujuhan                     100203        Kab. Bungo                     100200      Prov. Jambi                    100000                  SD         Negeri  02 Sep 2021 15:47:31  F32AAC8988739F022875                                                                                
14       SD NEGERI 80II KM. 57 TUKUM II  70478E5D-0C26-E111-B13E-4195E929DD49  10500663            17    7        2  117       6       6        0           1    Kec. Jujuhan                     100203        Kab. Bungo                     100200      Prov. Jambi                    100000                  SD         Negeri  31 Aug 2021 15:31:00  FE29577C773702FBC328
```

Comment: thank you so much. this is exactly what I need. Can you tell me where did you get the api_url?

Comment: @harjed I found the URL in Firefox Developer Tools -> Network Tab (Chrome has something similar). There are all requests the page is doing.